# How to make android email client pop up on the screen instead of leaving the screen

Tags: android, email, dialog, email-client

Am trying to make android email client pop-up on the same screen instead of leaving the screen, what presently happens is that when i implement this code and the button is clicked it leaves the present screen its on, but i want it to remain on that same screen or open as a dialog on the same screen

```
 Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.question);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"askme@gmail.com"});
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Ask questions");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> i want it to remain on that same screen

That is not possible. You cannot embed another app's activity's UI in your own.

> or open as a dialog on the same screen

That is not possible. You cannot force another app's activity's UI into a dialog.

On Android 7.0 devices where the user has enabled multi-window, you can [use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT) to request that the `ACTION_SEND` activity be opened in a separate window.

Comment: So do you have a solution or a recommended example to achieve it this. or is there any other approach entirely i can use

Comment: @Omega: "do you have a solution or a recommended example to achieve it this" -- your only option is covered in the last paragraph of my answer. "or is there any other approach entirely i can use" -- no, sorry.